# References of the dangers of misapplying Gaussianity?

Tags: normal-distribution, references

This may seem an uncommon request. I am preparing a presentation and for its introduction I am seeking illustrative, public, large-scale cases in which a wrong assumption of Gaussianity created a major problem. Due to the prevalence of the normal distribution and the frequency with which applied scientists tend to misapply it (for example when using it for random variables with physical limits, Pareto fronts, or multiple modes), I am quite sure that there must be some cases out there.

I am looking for references such as [this one](https://www.wired.com/2009/02/wp-quant/) which was about the dangers of misapplying and misunderstanding correlation. Anecdotal stories in papers, blogs, or newspapers would also be great!

Comment: Dangers of Gaussianity where? Not every statistical method assumes Gaussian distribution, so it is hard to discuss problems with breaking assumptions that were not made.

Comment: The question is about cases in which the assumptions made are broken, or should not have been justified in the first place.

Comment: Again: in what context? In some cases it would have small impact, in some, huge.

Comment: Any applied context: the global economy crashing due to neglecting uncertainty in correlation structures, spacecrafts exploding because a Kalman filter pulled the mean of a variable outside its physical limits, a hydropower-dam failure because the probabilistic estimate of a cotnrol variable was bimodal, not unimodal. Edit: I am primarily interested in larger cases: I assume smaller cases would not be reported on. I have clarified this above.

Comment: Did these changes clarify the question sufficiently?